# What does System.String[*] represent?

Tags: c#

All it is in the question, I have `Type.GetType("System.String[*]")` in some code, i don't know what this type is and can't really find anything about this star inside an array.

What key word will be relevant for this ?

Comment: Could you by any chance provide the context this was found in?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Type.GetType("MyArray[*]") gets a single-dimension array with unknown lower bound